# QField: QGIS actions

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qfield

I defined through QGIS a default action for a layer (load a raster which is referenced in a vector layer field) when the user clicks on the polygon geometry.

Is it possible to make QField execute this action? My code in QGIS is this:

```py
pathProj = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Parcels')
pathProj = pathProj[0].dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
pathProj = pathProj.replace('|geometrytype=Polygon|uniqueGeometryType=yes','BuildingPlans/')
pathProj=pathProj.replace('/','\\\\')
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(pathProj + '[% Georeferenced_Plan %]')
```

The code/Action is working fine in QGIS. I sync my project with QField Sync to my tablet. On the tablet the action does not trigger. In the Qfield docs I also do not find anything about QGIS actions - might not be supported yet?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i added the info to the question. ACtion is working, but in qfield nothing happens. In the docs of QField, actions are not mentioned

Comment: As I know, there is no Python support so far in QField, so your code can not work on a mobile device.

Comment: Your code seems to be aimed at windows platform. One problem might be the pathProj=pathProj.replace('/','\\\\') statement. I think android and iOS are using "/" in their path. Python in windows can handle that too, so make the replace the other way ('\\\\', '/') if really needed.
And yes, as eurojam points out, that's another possible issue. Maybe try another type of action to see if that succeeds.